# Qt Window Focusing: Main window is not focused when second-level child window is closed

Tags: windows, qt, qt4.7

First of all, sorry if the title does not make any sense.

So basically, I have a main window (`QMainWindow` instance labelled `MainWindow` for simplicity), which creates a child widget (`QWidget` instance labelled `Widget1`) at some point (for simplicity, this is done on a button click).

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Widget1 *w = new Widget1(this);
    w->show();
}
```

`Widget1` then creates another child widget (`QWidget` instance labelled `Widget2`, which is a different class than `Widget1`) at some point (again, for simplicity, this is done on a button click).

`Widget1` receives a `SIGNAL` from its child (`Widget2`), which is used for both sending another signal to its parent (`MainWindow`), and closing itself.

```
void Widget1::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Widget2 *w = new Widget2(this);
    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget2()), this, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget1()));
    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget2()), this, SLOT(close()));
    w->show();
}
```

After using `Widget2`, it emits a `SIGNAL` to its parent (`Widget1`), then is closed using its `this->close()` function.

```
void Widget2::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit testSignalWidget2();
    this->close();
}
```

My problem is that once this procedure is done, the window focus is not in the MainWindow, but on another window opened (If no other window is opened, this procedure shows the taskbar, even if `MainWindow` is shown as a fullscreen window). For reference, this issue only happened on Windows units; this did not happen on Ubuntu units I have tried on, which I use as primary OS. I used Qt 4.7.3 on all units.

Both `Widget1` and `Widget2` uses the following codes for setting their window flags and modality:

```
this->setWindowFlags( Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint );
this->setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal );
```

Can anyone please point out something I am doing wrong? Or maybe this approach is wrong right from the start, can anyone give some alternatives that can do the same procedures?

**EDIT:**
To answer the comment of SaZ, I have changed `MainWindow`'s call to `Widget1` as follows:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Widget1 *w = new Widget1(this);
    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget1()), this, SLOT(setFocus()));
    w->show();
}
```

However, this did not have an effect on the problem.

**EDIT:**

As per SaZ, I have posted the source code that I used to replicate this issue.

First, this was started with Qt's auto-generated Qt Gui Application. `Widget1` and `Widget2` are both auto-generated as Qt Designer Form Class.

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
//    w.show();
    w.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "widget1.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Widget1 *w = new Widget1(this);
    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget1()), this, SLOT(setFocus()));
    w->show();
}
```

widget1.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET1_H
#define WIDGET1_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget1;
}

class Widget1 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget1();

signals:
    void testSignalWidget1();
    void testSignalWidget1ToMain();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget1 *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET1_H
```

widget1.cpp

```
#include "widget1.h"
#include "ui_widget1.h"

#include "widget2.h"

Widget1::Widget1(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::Window );
    this->setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal );
}

Widget1::~Widget1()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget1::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Widget2 *w = new Widget2(this);
    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget2()),
            this, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget1()));
    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget2()),
            this, SLOT(close()));
    w->show();
}
```

widget2.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET2_H
#define WIDGET2_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget2;
}

class Widget2 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget2(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget2();

signals:
    void testSignalWidget2();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget2 *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET2_H
```

widget2.cpp

```
#include "widget2.h"
#include "ui_widget2.h"

Widget2::Widget2(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget2)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::Window );
    this->setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal );
}

Widget2::~Widget2()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget2::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit testSignalWidget2();
    this->close();
}
```

`mainwindow.ui`, `widget1.ui`, and `widget2.ui` each have a single push button, which are connected to their respective `on_pushButton_clicked()` function.

Comment: You may use `setFocus` method.

Comment: @SaZ I have added another connect statement to connect `testSignalWidget1()` signal to `setFocus` of `MainWindow`, but it did not affect anything.

Comment: You did nothing for now. There are no code, where you emit `testSignalWidget1`. Another question is: why you do `connect` inside `on_pushButton_clicked`?

Comment: Please, provide an SSCCE with your problem.

Comment: @SaZ When `Widget2` emits `testSignalWidget2()`, it is replicated to `Widget1` via `connect()`, which then emits `testSignalWidget1()`.

Comment: @SaZ I have added the sample source code I made to replicate my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by doing the following:

1. Remove the connection of `Widget2`'s `SIGNAL` and `Widget1`'s `close()` function.
2. Replace that connection with a local slot of `Widget1`.
3. Call `Widget1`'s `close()` function using `QTimer::singleshot()`.

widget1.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET1_H
#define WIDGET1_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget1;
}

class Widget1 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget1();

signals:
    void testSignalWidget1();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void testSlot();

private:
    Ui::Widget1 *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET1_H
```

widget1.cpp

```
#include "widget1.h"
#include "ui_widget1.h"

#include "widget2.h"

#include <QTimer>

Widget1::Widget1(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::Window );
    this->setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal );
}

Widget1::~Widget1()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget1::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Widget2 *w = new Widget2(this);
    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget2()),
            this, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget1()));
//    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget2()),
//            this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(w, SIGNAL(testSignalWidget2()),
            this, SLOT(testSlot()));
    w->show();
}

void Widget1::testSlot()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(close()));
}
```